# How to assign resource CPU and memory in supervisor jobs

Tags: linux, unix, supervisord

I am running jobs inside supervisor job tool of unix each job has its own configuration files but I could not find a way where I can set system resources in it like CPU and Memory.
Can someone let me know how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: `I could not find a way` So maybe there is none? Use a different tool. `nice` `ionice` cgroups `cpuset` etc.  `an set system resources in it like CPU and Memory` By "set" you mean "limit"?

Comment: yes by set I mean limit for each individual job